# An error occurred when using the FLUTTER APP to execute the LSTM deep learning module

Tags: flutter, dart, lstm, tensorflow-lite

When I press the button on the screen through this app, the data will be input to the lstm deep learning model, but an error will be reported after inputting the data. The following is the content of the code and the content of the error. I hope someone can help solve this problem. Thanks

content of the code:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class LSTMModelApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LSTMModelAppState createState() => _LSTMModelAppState();
}

class _LSTMModelAppState extends State<LSTMModelApp> {
  List<List<double>> input_data = [
    [
      0.1,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.4,
      0.5,
      0.6,
      0.7,
      0.8,
      0.9,
      1.0,
      1.1,
      1.2,
      1.3,
      1.4,
      1.5,
      1.6,
      1.7,
      1.8,
      1.9,
      2.0,
    ]
  ];
  List<double> _predictions = [];
  bool _isLoading = false;

  Interpreter? _interpreter;
  late List<int> _inputShape; // 新增變數來儲存輸入張量的形狀

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    loadModel().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> loadModel() async {
    String modelPath = 'assets/lstm_model.tflite';
    try {
      var interpreterOptions = InterpreterOptions();
      _interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset(modelPath, options: interpreterOptions);

      // 獲取輸入張量的形狀
      if (_interpreter != null) {
        var inputTensor = _interpreter!.getInputTensor(0);
        _inputShape = inputTensor.shape.toList(); // 將 shape 轉換為 List<int>
        print('Input shape: $_inputShape');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading model. Error message: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> runModel() async {
    for (var inputData in input_data) {
      var output = runModelOnInput(inputData);
      setState(() {
        _predictions.add(output);
      });
    }
  }

  double runModelOnInput(List<double> input) {
    var inputBuffer = Float32List.fromList(input).buffer;
    var outputBuffer = Float32List(1).buffer;
    var inputs = [inputBuffer];
    var outputs = [outputBuffer];
    _interpreter!.run(inputs, outputs);
    var output = outputBuffer.asFloat32List()[0];
    return output;
  }

  void printInputData() {
    String inputDataString = input_data.map((list) => list.toString()).toList().toString();
    print('Input data: $inputDataString');
    print('Input data shape: $_inputShape');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _interpreter?.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('LSTM Model App'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
          : Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              runModel();
              printInputData(); // 打印输入数据和形状
            },
            child: Text('Run Model'),
          ),
          if (_predictions.isNotEmpty)
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: LineChart(
                LineChartData(
                  minX: 0,
                  maxX: _predictions.length.toDouble() - 1,
                  minY: _predictions.reduce((curr, next) => curr < next ? curr : next),
                  maxY: _predictions.reduce((curr, next) => curr > next ? curr : next),
                  titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                    show: true,
                    bottomTitles: SideTitles(
                      showTitles: true,
                      getTitles: (value) {
                        return value.toString();
                      },
                    ),
                    leftTitles: SideTitles(
                      showTitles: true,
                      getTitles: (value) {
                        return value.toString();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  borderData: FlBorderData(show: true),
                  lineBarsData: [
                    LineChartBarData(
                      spots: _predictions
                          .asMap()
                          .entries
                          .map((entry) => FlSpot(entry.key.toDouble(), entry.value))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: LSTMModelApp(),
  ));
}
```

content of the error:

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:8737/tHVw3iC21zs=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
I/tflite  ( 5700): Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
I/flutter ( 5700): Input shape: [1, 20, 1]
I/flutter ( 5700): Input data: [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]]
I/flutter ( 5700): Input data shape: [1, 20, 1]
E/flutter ( 5700): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: failed precondition
E/flutter ( 5700): #0      checkState (package:quiver/check.dart:74:5)
E/flutter ( 5700): #1      Tensor.setTo (package:tflite_flutter/src/tensor.dart:166:7)
E/flutter ( 5700): #2      Interpreter.runInference (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:210:33)
E/flutter ( 5700): #3      Interpreter.runForMultipleInputs (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:180:5)
E/flutter ( 5700): #4      Interpreter.run (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:172:5)
E/flutter ( 5700): #5      _LSTMModelAppState.runModelOnInput (package:tf_lite_example/main.dart:84:19)
E/flutter ( 5700): #6      _LSTMModelAppState.runModel (package:tf_lite_example/main.dart:72:20)
E/flutter ( 5700): #7      _LSTMModelAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:tf_lite_example/main.dart:115:15)
E/flutter ( 5700): #8      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21)
E/flutter ( 5700): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
E/flutter ( 5700): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
E/flutter ( 5700): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
E/flutter ( 5700): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:239:7)
E/flutter ( 5700): #13     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:615:9)
E/flutter ( 5700): #14     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
E/flutter ( 5700): #15     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
E/flutter ( 5700): #16     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
E/flutter ( 5700): #17     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 5700): #18     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
E/flutter ( 5700): #19     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:460:19)
E/flutter ( 5700): #20     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22)
E/flutter ( 5700): #21     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337:11)
E/flutter ( 5700): #22     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7)
E/flutter ( 5700): #23     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5)
E/flutter ( 5700): #24     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7)
E/flutter ( 5700): #25     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter ( 5700): #26     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13)
E/flutter ( 5700): #27     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7)
E/flutter ( 5700): #28     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
E/flutter ( 5700):
```

I tried the following

1. Adjusted the shape of the input data but it didn't work
2. Because the output data has only one value, I thought it was because there cannot be only one point when drawing a line chart, so I reported an error, but it seems that this is not the reason

I tried the following

1. Adjusted the shape of the input data but it didn't work
2. Because the output data has only one value, I thought it was because there cannot be only one point when drawing a line chart, so I reported an error, but it seems that this is not the reason